# The definition of complementarity principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, definition, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality, phase-space

I am looking for a precise definition of [complementary principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity_(physics)). It is rather briefly mentioned in the textbook, and I feel that authors have deliberately avoided defining it precisely. I'm a math major, perhaps I didn't get the point. The most understandable description so far I found in wikipedia:

> "The complementarity principle holds that objects have certain pairs of complementary properties which cannot all be observed or measured simultaneously."

It is at best intuitive content. From the examples, it is not clear what properties are complementary properties. How can we consider the pair of complementary properties of a system? Would it enough considering non-commuting Hermitian operators?

Another definition I found in the book, "Niels Bohr and Complementarity" by Plotnitsky:

> Complementarity, then, is defined by
>
> (a) a mutual exclusivity of certain phenomena, entities, or conceptions; and yet
>
> (b) the possibility of applying each one of them separately at any given point; and
>
> (c) the necessity of using all of them at different moments for a comprehensive account of the totality
> of phenomena that we must consider.

Firstly, it is perhaps the Bohr's definition that Plotnitsky formulated as a comprehensive definition. Secondly, is it how physicists' community understand the complementarity principle? Thirdly, I just read somewhere that Bohr's correspondence principle implies the complementarity principle but correspondence principle was rejected during 80's. How about then fate of complementarity principle in the contemporary physics?

Comment: Please add the references you read, speak about, that might help people attempting to answer your question.

Comment: If you want concrete mathematical entities, familiarize yourself first, *cold*, with canonical conjugate variables and the uncertainty principles circumscribing them. This is thoroughgoingly antiquated language, one century old, meant to serve as code for UP inequalities. Given sufficient technical expertise, you would appreciate how to deconstruct/bypass your question.

Comment: The first problem with your quote is that "objects" don't exist in "modern physics". They are an approximation that works only for a very limited set of purposes in physics. The more you study physics, the more you will notice that the only fundamentally relevant "things" in physics are the locally conserved physical properties: energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges. Why these are fundamental is explained by Noether's theorem: they are the immediate consequence of the symmetries of the physical vacuum. All of them can be measured simultaneously just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the complementarity principle. One of those things that you read about and get confused mess mostly talked by philosophers. Then you read the original guy and find something completely different from what all those people were talking!

If you go to Bohr's "Discussions with Einstein on Epistemological Problems in Atomic Physics" you will find the following

> The new progress in atomic physics was commented upon from various sides at the International Physical Congress held in September 1927, at Como in commemoration of Volta. In a lecture on that occasion, I advocated a point of view conveniently termed "complementarity," suited to embrace the characteristic features of individuality of quantum phenomena, and at the same time to clarify the peculiar aspects of the observational problem in this field of experience. For this purpose, it is decisive to recognise that, however far the phenomena transcend the scope of classical physical explanation, the account of all evidence must be expressed in classical terms. The argument is simply that by the word "experiment" we refer to a situation where we can tell others what we have done and what we have learned and that, therefore, the account of the experimental arrangement and of the results of the observations must be expressed in unambiguous language with suitable application of the terminology of classical physics.

I.e.
1). The quantum physics is fundamental and contains classical physics as its limit
2). But we are macroscopic beings and all our experiments are formulated in classical terms
3). All theories in physics have to be formulated as statements about experiments

So here's the complementarity principle. We have to formulate the more fundamental quantum physics using its classical limit to make statements about the experimental setup. In this way the quantum and classical terms complement each other.

Comment: That quantum mechanics contains classical physics as a limit is false, for starters. Many quantum phenomena survive all the way to the classical scale and actually contradict any known version of classical physics. The most trivial and most important examples are the mere existence of stable matter. Less trivial and more obvious are e.g. permanent magnetism and superconductivity. Even less trivial are the periodic table of elements and the structure of chemistry and basically all effects in nuclear physics.

Comment: That's not complementarity, but one of the ideas of the Copenhagen interpretation (the classical theory is required to formulate experiments and how quantum theory is to be applied to explain/predict them). Complementarity is the idea that two different classical concepts may be applied to a quantum system even though strictly speaking, their existence/applicability is mutually exclusive in quantum theory; the more well-defined is the first concept (position), the less well-defined is the other (momentum). It's more of a philosophy than physics.

Answer (score -1):

This is only a partial answer to the question.  A quote from Wiki in the question states: "*The complementarity principle holds that objects have certain pairs of complementary properties which cannot all be observed or measured simultaneously.*"

While that may be a true concept as it applies to the specific term "complementarity", it is very deceptive.  It was known even early on (by 1935 for sure, really by 1927) that there is actually a trade off between one extreme (particle-like) and the other (wave-like).

Of course: you *can simultaneously* know both the momentum (wave-like property) and position (particle-like property) of a quantum object.  But there are strict limits on the precision of that knowledge.  That of course is embedded in the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle (HUP).  This trade-off applies to non-commuting observables, but does not apply to pairs of commuting observables (spin and momentum commute, for example).

The Complementarity Principle is often mentioned in lay or conversational terms.  But it is understood only to represent cases where focus is on a specific property or a specific quantum effect.  The HUP is the more general rule.